# Laravel. На сервере не авторизирует пользователя (регистрация работает), хотя на локальном работает все

Tags: laravel, авторизация, auth

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем можеть быть проблема.

Для создания использовал php artisan make:auth , менял логин на телефон, на локальном все нормально работает, а вот на сервере регистрирует пользователя, но если выйти, авторизироваться уже не получается.

В базе хеш пароля есть, он верный. Ввод верный. В консоли 302 Found. И никаких сообщений об ошибках. Дебаг включен.

В логе сервера нашел такое:

[Sun Jun 02 17:21:28 2019] [error] [client 46.98.123.125] File does not exist: /var/www/../data/www/site.ru/login, referer: https://site.ru/login.

Возможно, что-то с редиректом? Пробовал разные правила в htaccess - ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Проблема была где-то в папке vendor, на сервере оказалась не последняя версия